# pop up message while clicking the insert record button

Tags: javascript

I am pretty new to this PHP and MYSQL world, so if i am being dumb then apologies in advance and please bear with me.

I have a form, and before submitting the data into the sql table I want to give a POP UP message saying "Are you sure to insert the data in?".

Comment: Post your code... What have you tried? Just use jquery's confirm()

Comment: I'm sure "popup html" or "popup javascript" yields moar than enough results in google

Comment: have a look at [this](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_popup.asp)

Comment: @AndyHolmes: I have used this piece of code, but when i click on the pop up message button while inserting, it inserts two rows of the same data, instead of one. 'code' <tr valign="baseline">
                  <td nowrap="nowrap" align="right">&nbsp;</td>
                  <td><input onclick="return confirm('are u sure')" type="submit" value="Insert record" /></td>
                </tr>
              </table>

Comment: Sounds like more of a PHP issue than the javascript mate. Post some of your code inside your question so that everyone can see what you're working with

Answer (score -1):

You can't do it in PHP. Use JavaScript: `var insert = confirm("Are you sure to insert the data in....?")`

Comment: it's better to use confirm instead of alert